# How to check if value of cell is a subvalue of another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns with and ID such as "TCG45436" in both of them. Column one includes a number in parenthesis like "TCG45436 (5)". I need to check both columns to to see if the IDs match, and clear the cell contents of column two if they don't. The problem is the two won't match if column one includes the (5), but I only need the ID itself to match in both columns. I've done something similar in the past using substrings to find if columns 2 is a substring of column one, but I can't figure out how to apply that here.

Essentially, I want B30, and B32-B37 cleared in this snippet.

[image: Excel ScreenShot]

```
Sub TwoColumns()
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
Column1 = ActiveCell.Value
Column2 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value

If Column1 = Column2 Then 'needs to be If Column2 is equal to or a subvalue of Column1
Else
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: And b30 and b32 too? Is there always a space before the (x)?

Comment: @assylias Yes, sorry I can't read. This is why I don't want to do it manually for 1200 rows. I'll change it above and hope nobody notices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use the `InStr` function:

```
If InStr(0, Column1.Value, Column2.Value) <> 0 Then 'it's a substring.
```

Comment: Exactly the function I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Oops... 1) `!=` isn't VBA, use `<>`. 2) This won't compile because parentheses don't match. 3) After correcting these things, the condition will *always* be true since `InStr` cannot return -1... I hope @ChrisHull noticed this. I corrected your answer.

Comment: @Jean-François Corbett - I did notice both those things! Just learning of the INSTR was all I needed, and I managed to make those small changes to fit my needs. Thanks for editing the answer for us.